# How to make a table the same width as window so that scrollbars displays

Tags: html, html-table, width, horizontal-scrolling

I want to create a table with fixed headers and scrollable data rows.
I want the table to be the same width as the window. If the table is wider then the window you should be able to scroll the data horizontally.

Horizontall scrollbars dosen´t work in my current html code. Can someone please explain why? Here is a link for a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y73t4/)

```
<head>
  <style>
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div id="container" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <table>
              <tr id="tr">
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>123</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div id="container" style="overflow:scroll;">
            <table>
              <tr id="tr">
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>123</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="tr">
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome and it is working fine

Comment: I use IE9, FireFox and Chrome and it doesn´t work. The horizontal scrolbar ends up on the window not on the div.

Comment: Please simplify and format your code and put up a demo. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is a link to a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Y73t4/

Comment: Can it be done? Or is it because the columns gets a width beccause of the containing divs that make this impossible?  Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if I remove the first table-tag it works just fine. 
The table width gets the width of the window.

```
        <div>
      <div id="container" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <table>
          <tr id="tr">
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Kolumn123</div>123</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="container" style="overflow:scroll;">
        <table>
          <tr id="tr">
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr">
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="width:100px;">Table&nbsp;Cell</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nCee8/) where the table-tag is removed.

The problem is that the html-code will be inserted in the middel of a html-page and that page has a table around my html-code. Is there a way to get the width of the window even though the first table-tag remains?